# Matching groups without lookahead or lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's my question, I have an output like so:

```
[{"addr":"1","cid":1.3}]
```

I need to create a RegEx that could match both "1" and "1.3".
Code :

```
var reg = new RegExp(/(\d+?\([^a-zA-Z])(?![a-zA-Z])/);
x="[{"addr":"1","cid":1.3}]"
if (addr.match(reg)) {
    return msg;
}
return;
```

`addr` and `cid` could both range from 1 to 65536.

I did try something like `/(\d+?\([^a-zA-Z])(?![a-zA-Z])/` but it doesn't work.

I would like my output to be separated, from what I understand you can create groups but my RegEx knowledge is very limited.

Desired output: [1],[1.3];

Any idea?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex here. I would iterate the first object in the array and extract the values if they are in the given range.

Comment: why do you need regexp for some string that looks like a valid JSON data at first place? sounds like a typical X Y problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/209741

Comment: It was a XY problem indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of use a regex, you could use `JSON.parse` and use `Object.values` to get the values or the `reviver` function. Here the examples:

```js
var json = '[{"addr":"1","cid":1.3}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(json);

var res = arr.map(Object.values)[0]

console.log(res)


//reviver
var res2 = []

JSON.parse(json, (k,v)=>{
    if(+v >= 1 && +v <= 65536)res2.push(v);
})

console.log(res2)
```

Comment: Don't know why I forgot about JSON objects... Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

you could use
/\d.?\d?/g

see working example here
https://regexr.com/3ve0e